# Solve X=sqrt(A)^sqrt(A)^sqrt(A)^..............infinty?

Tags: calculus, power-towers

If
$X= \newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{\sqrt{A}^{.{^{.^{\dots}}}}}}}}}}}
$ then what is the value of $X^2-e^{1/X}$ ?

Comment: What is $X$? ${}{}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum convergent $x$ in the power tower $x^{x^{x^{x\cdots}}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948778/what-is-the-maximum-convergent-x-in-the-power-tower-xxxx-cdots) ; See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089458/how-can-i-prove-the-convergence-of-a-power-tower ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108288/infinite-tetration-convergence-radius

Answer (score 5):

You have $X= \sqrt{A}^X.$  So

$$\ln X = X \ln \sqrt{A} = \frac{X}{2}\ln A$$

$$\frac{2\ln X}{X} = \ln A$$

$$ A = \exp\left(\frac{2\ln X}{X}\right).$$

Comment: Sir,i got this result already but my ans should come A=x^2-e^1/x . i think i should edit my question upto this. or the answer given is wrong?

Comment: @Rohit:  this gives  a value for $A$, which could also be written $A=X^{\frac 2X}$.  Your question asks for the value of an expression in $X$.  Getting $X=$ some expression in $A$ looks difficult.  It could be handled numerically.  This only makes sense if $A \lt e^{\frac 2e}$ so the power tower converges.

Comment: @RossMillikan Don't forget $e^{-2e}\le A$.  Also, it converges when $A=e^{2/e}$ I believe...

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this has to converge, which occurs when $e^{-2e}\le A\le e^{2e^{-1}}$.  More elaboration on the convergence is discussed [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence).

$$X=A^{X/2}=e^{\frac12\ln(A)X}$$

$$Xe^{-\frac12\ln(A)X}=1$$

$$-\frac12\ln(A)Xe^{-\frac12\ln(A)X}=-\frac12\ln(A)$$

$$-\frac12\ln(A)X=W\left(-\frac12\ln(A)\right)$$

$$X=\frac{W\left(-\frac12\ln(A)\right)}{-\frac12\ln(A)}=e^{-W\left(-\frac12\ln(A)\right)}$$

Where I used the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  Now it's easy to compute the rest.